# Frozen Fork on 2011 Diamondback MTB

Tags: mountain-bike, fork, suspension

I have a frozen fork on a 2011 Diamondback Response MTB. It worked fine when I purchased it back then and was riding it regularly. It has sat in storage for the past 5 years and is now frozen. Can I still use it or should I purchase a new fork?

Comment: What shock?  Go to the web site and see if they sell a rebuild kit.

Comment: I'd just ride it around for a couple of days trying to take it off mild jumps and such. It's most probably just stiction (sticking friction) from old oil.

Comment: Even some of the budget shocks now have a lockout. Have you verified that your lever is not in the locked position?

Comment: Note - riding on a frozen front fork is not the same as a rigid fork - its heavier for no gain, and might suddenly release while riding.  If all the oil has gone, or any elastomer has broken then it may drop straight to the bottom (full compression) and surprise you as a rider, leading to a potential crash.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [Performance](http://www.performancebike.com/webapp/wcs/stores/servlet/mProduct4_10551_10052_1096075_-1_), your fork is a  "SR Suntour XCT with 100mm travel, 28.6mm stanchions".

These aren't really forks designed to be serviced -- they're basically the bare minimum of forks which are not completely for fashion statements. You can look on Youtube for videos of people trying to service them and what not -- you're basically going to strip it down as much as possible (which may require some penetrating oil), grease it up, and put it back together (you might get a head start on this by banging it a bit to see if it unsticks). Note that this is  maybe a 50 dollar fork, and depending on how much you value your time, you might want to take it into a shop to see if they can unstick it or just replace it, possibly with a rigid fork if you're trying to save money.